# Function doesn't work when ipcRenderer is used

Tags: javascript, html, electron, ipcrenderer

this is the first time I'm using electron so these could be some dumb questions but I didn't find anything online about it.

So, I have this in my `index.html` file

```html
<head>
    <script defer src="generate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="role">MY LABEL</label>
        <select name="abc" id="abc" class="abc">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
     <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
</body>
```

and this in my `generate.js` file

```js
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

const generate = () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('generate', document.querySelector('.abc').value)
}
```

In theory, whenever someone clicks on the button the `generate` function in the .js file should run, but it doesn't. I tried some testing and, removing ipcRenderer, the function get's highlighted (meaning it is in use) and the function works.
How do I solve this? If some other code is needed I'll share it.

EDIT: When removing ipcRenderer, I tried the code using `alert`

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I figured out the problem.
The external .js file (in this case `generate.js`), doesn't operate using NodeJS.
To fix this I had to add two lines of code on my `index.js` like so.

```js
const createWin = () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({

//these lines fixed the issue
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')
}
```